# Group corresponding rows value in a columns Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

There is a .csv file with 6 columns. Grouping is do be done based on duplicate values of column 1; all the values in corresponding columns (remaining 5) should be merged into a single column.
Sample Data

```
col1    col2            col3        col4    col5    col6
1234    Some Text       Reg1        Value1  Txt      A
2345    Any Text        Reg1        Value2  Txt      B
3456    Some Text       Reg2        Value3  Txt      C
1234    Another Text    Reg3        Value2  Txt      D
```

[Sample Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJPJd.png)

Below is the code, I am using

```
import csv
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   print('To few arguments, please specify input filename')
   sys.exit()

filename = sys.argv[1]

accs = {}
with open(filename, mode='rU') as f:

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for n, row in enumerate(reader):
    if not n:
        # Skip header row (n = 0).
        continue  
    acc, res, reg, col4, col5, col6 = row
    if acc not in accs:
        accs[acc] = list()
    accs[acc].append((res,reg,col4,col5,col6))

def listToStringWithoutBrackets(list1):
return str(list1).replace('[','').replace(']','')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
for key, value in accs.items():
    writer.writerow([key, listToStringWithoutBrackets(value)])


print("Output file, with a name Output.csv has been created in the current working directory!")
```

I have referred to [Sample Code for Group by in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985011/using-python-to-group-csv-data) Below is the result I am getting (as I have used List with Key as Col1 and other columns as values)

```
col1    col2
1234    (Some Text,Reg1,Value1,Txt,A),(Another Text, Reg3, Value2, Txt, D)
2345    (Any Text, Reg1, Value2, Txt, B)
3456    (Some Text,Reg2,Value3, Txt,C)
```

**Expected result (Actual result required)**

```
col1    col2                    col3        col4            col5        col6
1234    Some Text, Another Text Reg1, Reg3  Value1, Value2  Txt, Txt    A,D
2345    Any Text                Reg1        Value2          Txt         B
3456    Some Text               Reg2        Value3          Txt         C
```

**The expected (desired) result is required *without* using 3rd Party Library.**

Any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('1.csv'), delimiter=',')
ans = dict()
for n, row in enumerate(reader):
    if n == 0:
        titles = row
    else:
        num = row[0]
        if num in ans:
            t = ans[num]
            for i in range(1, len(row)):
                t[i].append(row[i])
        else:
            tmp = []
            for other in row:
                tmp.append([other])
            ans[num] = tmp

writer = csv.writer(open("2.csv", 'w'))
writer.writerow(titles)
for row in ans.values():
    tmp = []
    for key in row:
        if isinstance(t, str):
            tmp.append(key)
        else:
            tmp.append(",".join(key))
    writer.writerow(tmp)
```

Comment: This is what was required! **Thanks** @copie.